# Alamofire: 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type error

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I understand that this will throw error when use `weak` on non-reference type data. But, I use it on a class that is created by myself. Just wondering anyone having the same issue.

```
internal static func registeruUser(email email: String, username: String, password: String, completion: (user: TSUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    let baseURL = NSLocalizedString("sign_up", comment: "")
    let headers = ["Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"]
    let parameters = ["email": email, "name": username, "password": password]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, baseURL, headers: headers, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON {
        [weak self] response in // compiler error

        if let weakSelf = self {
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {

                    let json = JSON(value)
                    if let jsonUser = json["user"].dictionaryObject,
                        let user = Mapper<TSUser>().map(jsonUser) as TSUser? {

                            currentUser = user
                            weakSelf.storeUserToCache() // compiler error
                            completion(user: user, error: nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        completion(user: nil, error: NSError(domain: "ResponseError:Something wrong with data from [TSUser]registeruUser", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
                    }
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                completion(user: nil, error: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my class declaration:

```
@objc class TSUser: NSObject, Mappable, NSCoding
```

I am intended to call `storeUserToCache()` but got another error: `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call`

Here is the `func`:

```
private func storeUserToCache() {
    if let currentUser = TSUser.currentUser {
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(currentUser, toFile: self.getUserPath())
    }
}
```

Anyone has any ideas to go through the Swift compiler?

Comment: Since you have a static function `self` is not an object instance reference, so strong and weak do not have any meaning. If this was a  function that you were invoking on a class instance rather than the class itself then you can use strong/weak

Comment: @Paulw11 is correct, I'd like to add a side note. Your classes and structs are labeled 'internal' by default, so labeling them as such is superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paulw11 is correct. Because I am using `static`, that's why `self` does not make any sense. Low level mistake. Problem solved.